# Logging output from PsExec started from powershell

Tags: powershell, logging, psexec

I'm starting PsExec from powershell which works fine. All great. But i can't get it to log anything. It creates a file which is empty.

```
$InstallerFolder = "\\dc01\e"
$Domain = "domain"
$DomainUser = "admin"
$Password = "password"



$nodes = Get-Content "$InstallerFolder\Side-Scripts\nodes.txt"

foreach ($node in $nodes) {
$Arguments = @()
$Arguments += "\\$node"
$Arguments += "-u"
$Arguments += "$Domain\$DomainUser"
$Arguments += "-p"
$Arguments += "$Password"
$Arguments += "-h"
$Arguments += "`"$InstallerFolder\Side-Scripts\start.bat`""
$Arguments += ">>`"$InstallerFolder\logs\$node.txt`""
$Arguments += "-n"
$Arguments += "120"

Start-Process -Filepath "$InstallerFolder\Side-Scripts\PsExec.exe" $Arguments -NoNewWindow


}
exit;
```

I have also tried with 
    1>
    2>
    >
Same results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried the `-redirectstandardoutput` parameter of `Start-Process`?

Comment: Thank you. But that would give me the output of powershell, wouldn't it? I need the output generated by psexec.

Comment: Don't have time to test but if you need the output after the PSExec executes then this might work: $output = Start-Process -Filepath "$InstallerFolder\Side-Scripts\PsExec.exe" $Arguments -NoNewWindow; write-host $output

Comment: Nah, still just the powershell output.

Comment: what do you mean it would give you powershell output? -redirectstandardouptut gives you the output received over stdout... just try it and if it doesnt give you what you want then you have to clarify and give us samples

Comment: I misunderstood. The file is created but is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the redirect in the psexec line you can try sending it's output to a variable and then sending that output to a file like in the following.

```
$InstallerFolder = "\\dc01\e"
$Domain = "domain"
$DomainUser = "admin"
$Password = "password"

$psexec = "$InstallerFolder\Side-Scripts\PsExec.exe"

$nodes = Get-Content "$InstallerFolder\Side-Scripts\nodes.txt"

foreach ($node in $nodes) {
    $commandOutput = ((&$psexec \\$node `"$InstallerFolder\Side-Scripts\start.bat`" -u $Domain\$DomainUser -p $Password -h -n 120) | Out-String)
    $commandOutput | out-file "$InstallerFolder\logs\$node.txt"
}
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the delay. The file is created but is empty.